# how to add (gotfocus - lostfocus) events to all textbox in the project

Tags: vb.net

I created a project one year ago and now I want to add background color to all the focused textboxes.
I know I can create the events for all textboxes but it will take a lot of time, and I know that I can create a custom control (textbox) but I don't prefer.
so can I add those events for all textboxes in my project?

Comment: Build the Custom Control that you don't prefer, use the Find / Replace / Replace All tool of Visual Studio to replace all `New TextBox()` entries with `New MyTextBox()` and it's all done. -- The methods to override are `OnEnter()` and `OnLeave()` -- Assuming a WinForms Project, otherwise, specify the GUI framework you're using (`TextBox` is a very common name for Controls of any kind).

Comment: You have the listed the two possible solutions and said that you don't want to do either. Too bad then. I guess you're out of luck. The custom control is the obvious solution. Why don't you want to do that? If it's because it seems complex, don't worry about it. It's not complex at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through all the possibilities here.

Firstly, the usual thing to do with events is to create a distinct handler for each event of each control, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Enter
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Leave
    '...
End Sub
```

If you're doing the same thing for the same event of each control though, you can condense that into a single event handler per event:

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxes_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter
    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    '...
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxws_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave, TextBox2.Leave
    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    '...
End Sub
```

The `sender` parameter refers to the object that raised the event, so you can access the appropriate `TextBox` with a cast. The objects whose event you handle don't have to be the same type and you can even handle multiple events with the one method, as long as the signatures are compatible:

```vb
Private Sub Controls_FocusChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter,
                                                                            TextBox2.Enter,
                                                                            ComboBox1.Enter,
                                                                            TextBox1.Leave,
                                                                            TextBox2.Leave,
                                                                            ComboBox1.Leave
    Dim cntrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)

    'The event is raised before the change happens so the control
    'will have focus on Leave and will not have focus on Enter.
    cntrl.BackColor = If(cntrl.Focused, SystemColors.Window, Color.Yellow)
End Sub
```

Note that the designer can help you do this. You can select multiple controls, open the *Properties* window, click the *Events* button and then double-click the desired event to generate a single event handler with the selected event for all selected controls in the `Handles` clause. You can then select that existing event handler in the drop-down list for another event for one or more controls to add then to the `Handles` clause too. You can edit the method name in the code window as appropriate. You can also write the method and the `Handles` clause yourself if you want to.

Secondly, to write less code in each form, you can put your event handler(s) in a module somewhere and then use the `AddHandler` statement to attach it to the events when a form loads:

```vb
Module CommonEventHandlers

    Public Sub Controls_FocusChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim cntrl = DirectCast(sender, Control)

        'The control will have focus on Leave and will not have focus on Enter.
        cntrl.BackColor = If(cntrl.Focused, SystemColors.Window, Color.Yellow)
    End Sub

End Module
```

and:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each tb In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        AddHandler tb.Enter, AddressOf CommonEventHandlers.Controls_FocusChanged
        AddHandler tb.Leave, AddressOf CommonEventHandlers.Controls_FocusChanged
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    For Each tb In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        RemoveHandler tb.Enter, AddressOf CommonEventHandlers.Controls_FocusChanged
        RemoveHandler tb.Leave, AddressOf CommonEventHandlers.Controls_FocusChanged
    Next
End Sub
```

That will handle the events for all `TextBoxes` that were added directly to the form. If you want different controls and/or some are in child containers then you would need to adjust that accordingly. Note that the event handlers need to be removed when you're done.

Finally, the "proper" solution is to use a custom control. You create a custom control simply by adding a class to your project and then adding an `Inherits` line to that class. You then override the appropriate method for the event you would otherwise handle, e.g. `OnEnter` method for `Enter` event. The code you put in the method is basically the same as you would put in the event handler, except it refers to the current object rather than the `sender`:

```vb
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Private defaultBackColor As Color

    ''' <inheritdoc />
    Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)
        defaultBackColor = BackColor
        BackColor = Color.Yellow

        MyBase.OnEnter(e)
    End Sub

    ''' <inheritdoc />
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(e As EventArgs)
        BackColor = defaultBackColor
        MyBase.OnLeave(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can then just edit the designer code files of your existing forms to use that custom control instead of the standard `TextBox`, e.g. this:

```vb
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox
```

becomes this:

```vb
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.TextBox1 = New TextBoxEx()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBoxEx
```

That's just two lines of code changed per control, which you can do with the *Find & Replace* functionality. Everything will look and work exactly as it did before, but your `TextBoxes` will automatically exhibit the new behaviour. Once you've built your project, the custom control will be added to the *Toolbox*, so you can add it to forms in the designer like any other control.

Note that, in order to access the designer code files, you need to select your project or an item within it in the *Solution Explorer* and click the *Show All Files* button. You can then expand the node for your form and open the designer code file.